# aws ec2 my spring boot is runnig on port 8080 and I need to run on 80

Tags: spring-boot, dns, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-ec2-instance-connect, aws-route53

I have configure **AWS EC2 linux instance** . So I run my spring boot app on that instance. So When I start my app its post is **8080** so after deployment and my app is active then URL is like : **55.12.15.78:8080/myapp/**

Can any one help how to run my app with port 80 so I can access my app by 55.12.15.78/myapp/ or any way to work on that way.

Now I have domain name and I have configure the AWS ROUTE 53 service and its up also but when I hit the app I need to enter the URL like : **[www.myapp.com:8080/myabb/](http://www.myapp.com:8080/myabb/)**

Which is my issue.

I head by using the instance load balancer we can do that. But I do not have any idea to configure that too.

Answer (score 0):

The default port where a Spring Boot app runs is 8080. You can edit your `application.properties` or `application.yml` file and change the port to `80`. Re-start the application, your application should be running on port `80` then.

```
# application.properties
server.port=80
```

or

```
# application.yml
server:
  port : 8081
```

There are many other ways to configure the port in a Spring Boot application. You can find more details here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-port

Answer (score 0):

I just run my application on ec2 with this commend and server get started.

**java -Dserver.port=80 -jar myapp.war**

Also I configured load balancer of EC2 which will handle https request.